# Preventing Duplicate Values in a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a hard time preventing duplicate values from inserting into a specific table in Microsoft SQL Server.  I have a staging table that I import data into each month and from this table Insert all the phone numbers into a phone numbers table. The Phone Numbers table is a simple table with 1 column and that column is set as the primary key.

The first time I go to insert the data from the staging table to the phone table, everything is fine because I can use `distinct` in my insert query to make sure there are no duplicates that enter into into the Phone Numbers table. The issue arises when I want to add another months worth of data and I have to compare what's in the new months data to whats in the Phone Numbers table.

Here is where I'm currently at, but this query is returning a `The multi-part identifier "tbl_PhoneNumber.MTN" could not be bound.` error

```
INSERT INTO tbl_PhoneNumber( MTN )
SELECT distinct [dbo].[tbl_Raw_Data].[Wireless Number]
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Raw_Data]

Where  tbl_PhoneNumber.[MTN] <>[tbl_Raw_Data].[Wireless Number]
```

Hopefully I didn't make this sound more confusing then what it is. What is the best way to compare two tables and only insert unique values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Duplicate Checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842/sql-server-duplicate-checking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure you have a column called `MTN` in your table and it should work fine.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_PhoneNumber( MTN )
SELECT distinct [Wireless Number]
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Raw_Data]
Where NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM tbl_PhoneNumber
                 WHERE tbl_PhoneNumber.[MTN] = [tbl_Raw_Data].[Wireless Number])
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and I will accept it as the answer as soon as it lets me. I do have a questions though. What is purpose of the `1` after `select`? I tried something similar to this earlier, but didn't include the 1.

Comment: actually it doesnt have to be `1` it could be anything even a `SELECT NULL` will work just fine, actually exist operator just looks for anything, if anything is returned from the sub-query where the `where` condition evaluates to true the whole expression is evaluated to true for that particular row in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way.

```
insert into tbl_PhoneNumber (mtn)
select distinct Wireless_Number 
from tbl_Raw_data
except
select mtn
from tbl_PhoneNumber
```